# Number of possible sentences

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Given the Spanish Alphabet, which contains $27$ letters ($5$ vowels: a,e,i,o,u; and $22$ consonants, which are the same as in English, but including "eñe",ñ), I am asked to find how many different sentences of $8$ words and having a total of $20$ letters are there, taking into account that words are separeted with each other by a space (a fact that acts as a separator between words) and that each word contains at least one letter. Here is my attempt:

To begin with, I need to find how many ways are there to distribute those $20$ letters in $8$ words. The words are distinguishable and I think that the order does matter since this is actually one of the points that make two sentences different despite maybe having all the same words. Therefore, one has to find the number of solutions of $x_1 + \cdots x_8 = 20, x_i \geq 1$, which is $19 \choose 7$. Having done that, the only remaining problem would be finding how many possible words are there. Since the difficult part has already been done and since all letters sum $20$, there are $27^{20}$ options, and therefore, using the product rule, there are ${19\choose 7}
 \cdot 27^{20}$ possibilities.

Comment: Assuming you do not care about if the words are pronouncable or actually mean anything, sure.  Once you care about each word containing a vowel or such then this is can be a slippery slope and more and more conditions might be added.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Indeed, in this questions there is not assumed any other condition of how the words must be or whether if they have sense